# I am getting 400 Bad Request for ReST call only in internet explorer

Tags: java, rest, api

In our running application, one of **GET** request starts giving response as *400 Bad Request* in Internet Explorer.

On investigating , I found that GET request doesn't have queryParameters what were expected by ReST call.

As it is giving response in another browsers like Chrome, Mozilla,
how can I proceed further ?

this is **Request** currently being triggered--

Method of request is **GET**

**https://XXXXXXXXX/XXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX?{%22numRecords%22:1000,%22start%22:0}&_=1487576597960**

and queryParameters in **@QueryParam** expected by ReST api are-

-numRecords
-start

I know by the above GET request, numRecords and start will not get captured by api backend.

So , is there any chance, if my GET request lack of any **@QueryParam** will lead to 400 Bad request response.

Comment: ... well ... provide the queryParameters maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found that GET request doesn't have queryParameters

You can use query parameters in GET requests as you've provided in your example like this: `http://host?queryParam1=value1`. however it's not possible to pass a request body as you can do for POST or PUT requests to provide JSON encoded data for example. You can work around this by adding the JSON **AND** URL encoded payload to a query parameter. But you endpoint explicitely has to be able to read this parameter. So you should add this parameter to your definiotn like in this example for JAX-RS:

```
@GET
@Path("my-endpoint")
public String request(
        @PathParam("payload") JsonObject payload
) {
```

What you've tried is to simply pass the payload data without specifing the name of the request parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @thomas-mc-work As it has no queryParameters, is there any chance in IE as getting 400 Bad Request ?

Comment: @RaviKarn I can not imagine that this is working in any browser. However if it does then maybe it helps to decode the curly brackets too: replace `{` and `}` by `%7B` and `%7D`. And maybe the colon too: `:` => `%3A`